# Django Can not get value of related model data in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'd like to show the likers of each post below it.

Here are the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def likers(self):
        return self.postlike_set.all()


class PostLike(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    liker = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name="post_liker")
```

And in the template I  have:

```
  {% for post in posts %}

   <div>{{ post.created |timesince }}</div>
   <div>{{ post.creator }}</div>
   <div>{{ post.title }}</div>
   <div>{{ post.body }}</div> 
   <ul>
      {% for liker in post.likers %}
           <li><a href="/path/to/profile/{{ liker.name}}">{{ liker.name}}</a></li> 
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>

   {% endfor %}
```

But nothing appears in the template.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `likers` method returns a queryset of `PostLike` objects. If you want the usernames of the likers, then you need to follow the `liker` foreign key to the `User` model.

You also have `liker.name` which isn't going to work unless your `User` model has a `name` field. Use something like `liker.username` or `liker.first_name`.

```
  {% for post_liker in post.likers %}
       <li><a href="/path/to/profile/{{ post_liker.liker.username }}">{{ post_liker.liker.username }}</a></li> 
  {% endfor %}
```

In this case, it would probably be simpler to use a many-to-many field instead of creating your own joining table.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    likers = models.ManyToManyField('User')
```

Then you don't need the `likers` method in your model, and your template would simplify to:

```
  {% for liker in post.likers.all %}
       <li><a href="/path/to/profile/{{ liker.name }}">{{ liker.username }}</a></li> 
  {% endfor %}
```